# What is the size of a function?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes

I'm not sure whether this question should be asked on mathoverflow.com or here, but as it is in the context of computational complexity, I will ask here.

### Context

Oded Goldreich states in his book *Computational Complexity: A Conceptual Perspective* (no advertising intended!) that a search problem is in *PC* (Polynomial-Time Check) if it fulfills this condition among others:

> There exists a polynomial $p$ s.t. if $(x, y) \in R$ then $|y| \leq p(|x|)$.

### Question

If the solution to a search problem is a function, how is the *size* of the function ($|y|$) determined? I thought, it could be size of the *input* of that function, but I am not sure.

Comment: Markus?! ;)  Anyway, the question is really too basic here. (but: y is just a string. It could be encoding a function or anything else for that matter)

Comment: @Kristoffer: Ups, I wanted to verify the name first ;) Yeah it is probably too basic, sorry for that. What would be the place to ask such questions?

Comment: For what it’s worth, this question would be too basic on MathOverflow, too.  You might want to try at http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a basic question, yet I tend to answer simple ones too :)

In the book you mentioned, take a look at section 1.2.1 (page 18). It describes how various objects are encoded. Among other things, it includes a section "Strings," in which "relation encoding" is described:

At times, we associate $\{0, 1\}^∗ \times \{0, 1\}^∗$ with $\{0, 1\}^∗$; the reader should merely consider an adequate encoding (e.g., the pair 
$(x_1 \dots x_m, y_1 \dots y_n) \in \{0, 1\}^∗ \times \{0, 1\}^∗$ 
may be encoded by the string $x_1x_1 \dots x_mx_m01y_1 \dots y_n \in \{0, 1\}^∗$).

Functions are a special type of relation, so they can be similarly encoded. In particular, a (finite and discrete) function can be seen as a list of input-output relations: $f=\{(x_1,y_1),\dots,(x_n,y_n)\}$. This can be easily encoded by incorporating a special symbol, say $\circ$. That is, $enc(f)=x_1 \circ y_1 \circ \dots \circ x_n \circ y_n$. (The encoding can be done without any special symbol, but it adds unnecessary intricacy.)

This way, the size of $f$ is the size of its encoding: $|enc(f)| \approx \sum_{i=1}^{n}{(|x_i|+|y_i|)}$.

Needless to say, infinite functions have infinite size, unless you can compress the list somehow. (This brings up the "[Kolmogorov Complexity Theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity)", which is a story for another day!)

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer this :) It will definitely help me to go on.

Comment: Any time! Just make sure criticism does not prevent you from asking :)